# how to concatenate 2 columns in the same data set in R

Tags: r

I have a data set in the following order:

```
Date    Time    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  NumberOfTrades  BidVolume   AskVolume
1   2011/12/22   02:00:00   5805.5  5820.5  5804.0  5820.5  253 96  161 71
2   2011/12/22   02:01:00   5819.0  5820.0  5813.0  5817.0  77  57  43  23
3   2011/12/22   02:02:00   5816.5  5820.0  5816.0  5819.0  30  22  9   14
```

I need to add a column before column a (`Date`) that will be `A+B` (`"Date"` `"Time"`) and than I will be able to make my dataset an XTS (XTS needs a unick key)

The final result will be something like:

```
DateTime             Date       Time       Open   High  Low Close   Volume  NumberOfTrades  BidVolume   AskVolume
1   2011/12/22 02:00:00  2011/12/22  02:00:00   5805.5  5820.5  5804.0  5820.5  253 96  161 71
```

Thanks

Comment: It's better to just refer to columns by their actual names (for example, `Date` and `Time` in this case) and avoid using generic letters (like A and B) that have meaning in spreadsheet programs like Excel, but do not have any intrinsic meaning in `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `paste` to combine the `Date` and `Time` columns and `as.POSIXct` to convert the string to date-time class.

Assuming your data frame is called df:

```
df$DateTime = as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time))
```

After you've added `DateTime` to your data frame, per @RichardScriven's comment, you can rearrange the order of the columns as follows:

```
df = df[ , c(length(df), 1:(length(df)-1))]
```

Or, you can add `DateTime` as the first column as follows:

```
df = data.frame(DateTime=as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time)), df)
```

Comment: Instead of calling `data.frame`, you can rearrange the columns with `df[c(length(df), 1:(length(df)-1))]`

Comment: I know, but this seemed like the most straightforward and least prone to error for someone new to `R`.

Comment: 1 more q. if I may, I have 2 data frames with different length of lines (the amount of days is different). How can I match the 2 df to be with the same length and when the above column is used as the index for the matching. thanks again!

Comment: If you want to merge rows from the 2nd data frame (let's call it `df2`) with the same `Date` and `Time` as a row in the first data frame (`df1`) then use `merge`. For example: `merge(df1,df2, by=c("Date","Time"), all.x=TRUE)`. This will keep all rows of `df1` and merge in all matching rows from `df2`. To keep only rows in `df1` with a match in `df2` set `all.x=FALSE`). Note that if there are several rows in `df2` with the same `Date` and `Time` as a row in `df1`, then `merge` will add an additional row to  the output data frame for each additional matching row in `df2`.

Comment: thanks. i will try this later because now i have an issue with the main thread here. I reopen my rstudio and now when I run the same line that worked before "XG1min = data.frame(DateTime=as.POSIXct(paste(XG1min$Time)), XG1min)" I get an error: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. How and why did it work before but not now?

Comment: There's a problem with your code. You did `XG1min = data.frame(DateTime=as.POSIXct(paste(XG1min$Time)), XG1min)`. Change to: `XG1min = data.frame(DateTime=as.POSIXct(paste(XG1min$Date, XG1min$Time)), XG1min)`. The error message is telling you that the result of `paste(XG1min$Time)` is not in a format `as.POSIXct` can work with.

Comment: @eipi10 thanks, i fixed it and although there is no error, my first column in XG1min dataframe is holding "Date" only with no "time": DateTime   Date       Time Open High Low Close
1 2011-12-22 2011/12/22 02:00:00 5805.5 5820.5 5804.0 5820.5. The time column is not being copied.

Comment: Please post, as an update to your question, the code you're running and a sample of both the input (if different from the data frame sample you posted originally) and output data frames.

Comment: I reposted a q. @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546627/setting-a-column-to-be-numeric-in-pair-trading